# Valgrind has reported "memory leak" when I compiled my program with "-pg" enabled?

Tags: linux, memory, profiling, valgrind, memory-leaks

I've get a memory leak reported by Valgrind with -pg enabled when compiling the following simple code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3

using boost::filesystem::path;

using namespace std;

int main() {

        path ptDir;
        ptDir = "/home/foo/bar";

        if (true == is_directory((const path &)ptDir)){
                cout << "ptDir: " << ptDir << endl;
        }
}
```

The full compile option was as follows.

```
g++ -pg -g test.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

The command of running valgrind is:

```
valgrind --gen-suppressions=all --track-origins=yes --error-limit=no --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes -v --trace-children=yes --track-fds=yes --log-file=vg.log ./a.out
```

Then valgrind gave me a memory leak error.

```
==9598== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9598==     in use at exit: 4,228 bytes in 1 blocks
==9598==   total heap usage: 136 allocs, 135 frees, 17,984 bytes allocated
==9598==
==9598== Searching for pointers to 1 not-freed blocks
==9598== Checked 130,088 bytes
==9598==
==9598== 4,228 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==9598==    at 0x402A5E6: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==9598==    by 0x4260F44: monstartup (gmon.c:134)
==9598==    by 0xBED6B636: ???
==9598==    by 0x4E45504E: ???
==9598==
{
   <insert_a_suppression_name_here>
   Memcheck:Leak
   fun:calloc
   fun:monstartup
   obj:*
   obj:*
}
==9598== LEAK SUMMARY:
==9598==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9598==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9598==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9598==    still reachable: 4,228 bytes in 1 blocks
==9598==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9598==
==9598== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==9598== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is this correct? I'm using Ubuntu 12.04/ Kernel 3.2.0-32-generic

Comment: You should "believe" `valgrind`, but I won't be surprised if profiling functions don't free all their memory. Try to compile without `-pg` to see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 2):

[Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.deflost):

```
"still reachable" means your program is probably ok -- it didn't free some 
memory it could have. This is quite common and often reasonable. Don't use
--show-reachable=yes if you don't want to see these reports.
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the allocatio comes from:
`by 0x4260F44: monstartup (gmon.c:134)`
indicates that it's a side effect of -pg - which is nothing you can do anything about. Don't mix -pg and valgrind is my suggestion.